# What's the correct output of using inline-block and adding padding to the nodes?

Tags: html, css

I have the following code, I am trying to understand why all the elements are not layed out on the same line. It's because I added padding, but shouldn't the padding be accounted for when laying out the elements? I checked on IE, Firefox, and Chrome. They all lay out the last element on the next line.

Can someone explain why, and how do I get all the elements on the same line and keep the padding I put on them?

Thanks

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style>
.body{PADDING:0PX;MARGIN:0PX}
.bar{WIDTH:100%;HEIGHT:20PX;BACKGROUND-COLOR:#FFFFFF;}
.item{WIDTH:25%;HEIGHT:20PX;DISPLAY:INLINE-BLOCK;COLOR:#000000;PADDING:5PX;}
</style>
</head>

<body class="body">
<div id="menubar" class="bar">
   <div  class="item">B1</div>
   <div  class="item">B2</div>

   <div  class="item">B3</div>
   <div  class="item">B4</div>
</div> 
</body>
</html>
```

B4 display on a new line.

The output I want is:

```
B1 B2 B3 B4
```

The output I get is:

```
B1 B2 B3
B4
```

Comment: This is painful, please write your CSS in lower case. `{padding:0px; margin:0px}` is the accepted and expected way of writing CSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `inline-block` layouts, the elements are affected by whitespace and vertical layout, in addition to any padding you add. When working with this form of layout, it's best to always use `vertical-align: top;`. This gives you a consistent starting point to work from.

The whitespace problem with `inline-block` is that any spaces between elements in your HTML get treated just like they would with text in HTML and get condensed into a single space. So, in addition to any padding or margins you've set, you have this space to deal with. To get rid of it you can bunch your elements together, or comment out the whitespace.

So in your case, in addition to the 25%, it's adding whitespace and padding. The easiest fix is to change your padding to top and bottom only. Since your design is a flex layout, your left and right padding is taken care of another way: by the stretchiness of it. If there is an issue with the text being butted up against a border on the left, you can use `text-indent: 5px;` as a replacement for `padding-left: 5px;`. It doesn't affect layout.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ThinkingStiff/xAEhY/

Change:

```css
.item{WIDTH:25%;HEIGHT:20PX;DISPLAY:INLINE-BLOCK;COLOR:#000000;PADDING:5PX;}
```

To:

```css
.item {
    color: #000000;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 20px;
    padding: 5px 0 5px 0;
    text-indent: 5px;
    width: 25%;
}
```

Here's a demo that illustrates the issues with `inline-block` layouts and how to deal with them.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ThinkingStiff/axjba/

HTML:

```html
<div id="container">
    <div class="child">one</div>
    <div class="child">two</div>
    <img class="child" />
</div>

<div id="container-align">
    <div class="child-align">one</div>
    <div class="child-align">two</div>
    <img class="child-align" />
</div>

<div id="container-align-whitespace">
       <div class="child-align">one</div><!--
    --><div class="child-align">two</div><!--
    --><img class="child-align" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
.child {
    border: 1px solid red;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
}

.child-align {
    border: 1px solid red;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 50px;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 50px;
}

#container, #container-align, #container-align-whitespace {
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 100px;
    width: 300px;
}
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You are setting each of the four items to 25% width + 10px of horizontal padding. This means that there will be 40px of width that will cause the fourth item to wrap.

If you want to use padding on the same element to which you apply width, you'll need to use a percentage, like `width: 23%; padding: 5px 1%;`. Or, you could apply the padding to an interior element so that the only dimension on your items is the width.

Comment: Don't forget that `display:inline-block` also renders 4px to the right of each element :). +1.

Comment: @AndresIlich, if I'm not mistaken, the amount of space added below/to the right of an `inline-block` element is based on the `font-size` property, and is not a set size (`4px`).

Comment: @bfrohs Yes. It's a single whitespace character, the width defined by the current font size.

Comment: What do multiple values like `5px 1%` do? Could you give me a link to some explanation?

Comment: @bfrohs i thought the same at first, but through testing i found it to be about 4px regardless of `font-size`. Test here: http://jsfiddle.net/andresilich/fdvu7/

Comment: @AndresIlich, not of the `inline-block` element, but of the parent. See this [altered jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/fdvu7/2/).

Comment: @bfrohs better illustrated here, with colors! http://jsfiddle.net/andresilich/fdvu7/1/ (change the margin-right to -4px).

Comment: @wrongusername, `padding: 5px 1%;` is the same as `padding: 5px 1% 5px 1%;` where `padding: TOP RIGHT BOTTOM LEFT;`.

Comment: @bfrohs ahhh, see what you mean, you're right, though depending on the granularity of your font sizing in your design both cases can be true (right?). TIL!.

Comment: @AndresIlich `margin-right: -4px;` is not the answer. It can be different based on font size as @bfrohs demonstrated.

Comment: @bfrohs Aha, thanks! I was thrown off as I had never seen two different units being used together like that

Comment: @wrongusername, no prob. Also, another thing you might come across is three values listed instead of four. Quick cheatsheet: `padding: AAA;` = `padding: AAA AAA AAA AAA;` ***AND*** `padding: AAA BBB;` = `padding: AAA BBB AAA BBB;` ***AND*** `padding: AAA BBB CCC;` = `padding: AAA BBB CCC BBB;`.

Answer (score 1):

`width` and `height` in CSS apply to the `content box` (inside the padding/border/margin). So, when you set a `width` and `padding`, the total width of the element is computed to `width`+`padding-left`+`padding-right`. To overcome this, you can either adjust the `width` accordingly, or set the `box-sizing` property of CSS3 to `border-box`. This makes the width include the `padding` and `border`, and therefore is not affected by changing `padding` or `border` values. The `margin` property will still affect the total width, however.

To fix, add this to your CSS:

```
.item {
 box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

For more information, see http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-ui/#box-sizing

***Note:** You may need browser prefixes to get this to work in some browsers, and it may not work at all in others. Be sure to test first to see if it fits your needs.*

Answer (score -1):

Add another block element around Bs. If it's a menu, transform the anchor tag to:

```
#menubar a{display: block; padding: 5px}
```